# Backbone collection.findWhere issue - Erroring on collection

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I am writing a backbone (with require) application and need to search through a collection to pull out the first model (I'm using a unique id so there will only be one).

The issue I'm having is that I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'findWhere'
```

When it get to the line with the findWhere command.

The view initialization is:

```
initialize: function (models) {
    this.locationCollection = new LocationCollection();
    this.locationCollection.fetch();

    this.render();
},
```

I then access the locationCollection later in another method, the first line of the method is where the error occurs:

```
createCrate: function (eventname) {
    var setLocationList = this.locationCollection.findWhere({ Name: $('#location').val() });
    console.log($('#location').val());
    console.log(setLocationList);        
},
```

Here is the declaration code the LocationCollection:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'model/LocationModel'
], function ($, _, Backbone, LocationModel) {

   var LocationCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: LocationModel,
      url: "/api/locations"
   });

   return LocationCollection;

});
```

I can access the items in this.localCollection elsewhere in the view and output them into a backbone typeahead extension, so the collection has been populated.

Any idea why this collection cannot call findWhere?

Comment: can you add the declaration code for LocationCollection?

Comment: Random guess : Underscore version < 1.4.4 or Backbone < 1.0.0 ?

Comment: Ah. Spot on: Backbone 0.9.9 and Underscore 1.4.3

Comment: Add the updated version and all is well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [`_.findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) was introduced in [Underscore 1.4.4](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog)
- and Backbone proxied it in [Backbone 1.0](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog)

Make sure you have the adequate versions and your error should go away.